# mysql write select subquery on same table with condition on the resultset

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to get all the data from users table with createdBy populated with name matching userid.

**means**

> instead of showing createdBy column with id, I want to show createdBy
>   name querying by userid. Is there any possibility. Please help me.

table: User

```
This is what i get
```

[image]

> This is what i need

[image]

Comment: Use a self join, then select the createdBy field (which is an alias for the name one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use self join

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=de6d86f2b390dbadfdcf45cee3e72d03)

```
 select a.*,b.name as createdbyname from user a left join user b 
 on b.id=a.createdby
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48a6e3/1) should do the trick. You join the table with itself (actually, with only the userid and names fields, to avoid conflicts with the original createdBy field) on the matching userids, then select only the relevant fields

```
SELECT u.userId, u.name, sj.createdBy
FROM users u JOIN (SELECT userId, name AS createdBy FROM users) AS sj
ON u.createdBy = sj.userId
```